# jquery calling function from document ready

Tags: jquery

I see a bunch of similar questions, but didn't find the answer I need .  I have this function:

```
function fnGetContent(keyword) {
    var NewKeyword = keyword.tag;
    var type = keyword.type;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  //GetEvents(iType As Integer, sSearch As String)
        url: "Default.aspx/GetEvents",
        data: "{'iType':'"+ type +"','sSearch' : '" + NewKeyword + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var res = unescape(msg.d);
            $("#divResults").html(res);
            $('.accordian_body').hide();
            $('.accordian_head').click(function () {
                $(this).next().animate(
                    { 'height': 'toggle' }, 'fast'
                );
                $('.plus', this).toggleClass('subtract');
                $('#<%= tSearch.ClientID %>').val() = 'Search by event, team, artist or venue';
            });       
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

It works fine being called from here:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fnGetContent({'type' : '2', 'tag' : 'concert'});">TEST TAG</a>
```

But I also want to call this function on my `Document.Ready` , I want it to run right when the page is loaded , then I will call it every time I want the results to be updated through `<a href>`  .  THis does not work , other answers to similar questions were to not call a function defined out side of ready, I know it is possible to call the same function from multiple spots including Document.Ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function fnGetContent("{'type' : '2' , 'tag' : ' ' }");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this , I figured it out , don't write function, and without the quotes

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fnGetContent({'type' : '1' , 'tag' : ' ' });
});
```

Comment: Yes, of course not the `function` keyword when you are *calling* the function. I wasn't looking for more than one error...

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotation marks, so that you pass in an object to the function instead of a string:

```
function fnGetContent({'type' : '2' , 'tag' : ' ' });
```